# using try catch causing errors;

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;



public class divide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int a,b;

        try{
            System.out.println("enter 2 number ");
            a = kb.nextInt();
            b = kb.nextInt();
            int c = a/b;
            System.out.println("div="+c);

        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println("please enter non 0 in deno");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e2)
        {
            System.out.println("please input int only");
            System.exit(0);

        }
        int d= a+b;
        System.out.println("sum="+d);
    }
}
```

error

divide.java:38: error: variable a might not have been initialized
        int d= a+b;
               ^
divide.java:38: error: variable b might not have been initialized
        int d= a+b;

Comment: The compiler does not approve your question title

Comment: Local variable do not have initial values. You must initialize the variable with some value. Refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Comment: This has nothing to do with try/catch.  You're simply not initializing your variables, so the compiler can't guarantee that they will be initialized when you're using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the way a try/catch block works, there's no guarantee that the statements inside it actually get run. (Because there could be an error, resulting in them just getting skipped.)

Because of that, Java can't guarantee that a and b have been defined, when you try to reference them. In this case they always will have been, because you're exiting in the catch statement.

You can solve this by giving them initial default values, or moving the referencing code into the try block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize you variable

```
int a =0,b=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your **try-catch** fails no matter why/how  when reading a, then the variable b is never initialized...
the app jumps to the catch block, and  at the end you do:

```
int d= a+b;
System.out.println("sum="+d);
```

**What is supposed to be the value of `b` in that case??**

## the quick fix is:

declare and init the variables...

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```